# Import function loses <p> tags

Tags: import

I have used the export function to download all my posts from one installation of wordpress, and then imported the file into a second. However the imported posts have been stripped of all paragraph breaks. I looked in the XML export file, and the p tags all seem to be in there. Is there a problem with the import function? And how can I get all the paragraph breaks back again? Any suggestions much appreciated!
Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is by design. WordPress saves posts without `<p />`'s unless you explictly add them in the HTML component of the editor.

When you import content, each post is passed through a filter so that it behaves as if the post were 'being saved'.

WordPress will then generate paragraphs on-the-fly when a post is viewed on the front-end of the website.